# Unable to send complete error stack in nodemailer using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

My program triggers an email in case of any error in the running code. But my problem is that is it only send the very first line of the error.

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
```

instead of the complete error stack of:--

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
    at Object.handle (D:\QlikIntermediate\routes\index.js:93:19)
    at next_layer (D:\QlikIntermediate\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:
103:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\QlikIntermediate\node_modules\express\lib\router\route
.js:107:5)
    at D:\QlikIntermediate\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:213:24
    at Function.proto.process_params (D:\QlikIntermediate\node_modules\express\l
ib\router\index.js:286:12)
    at next (D:\QlikIntermediate\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:182:38
)
    at next (D:\QlikIntermediate\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:182:38
)
```

Without the complete error stack its very difficult for me to trace the error. I have tried different styles in html tag of nodemailer but it only send the main error line. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your code, but have you confirmed that nodemailer is getting the full error object and not just the message sent up? You can also try ex.stack

Comment: Thanx @Mankind1023 , ex.stack and in email function `${errorMessage}` resolved the issue.